# If you click the browser back button on angular2, only url changes

Tags: angular

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router){}

this.router.navigate(['/'], {
    queryParams: {
        myQueryParam: 'test'
    }
});
```

when i click my item this router changes my url to localhost:3000/?myQueryParam=test

But only the url changes when i click browser back button.

Here is my plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/DlcNeOqjUsIZJAwmj76Y?p=preview